# httpd url rewrite rules issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, apache2.4

I am trying to fix an old project which is using `.htaccess` file for httpd.

`.htaccess` has two rules for rewriting path if no date is in the path it will go to the index otherwise to list. The problem is the list path does not work, it goes into index, if I comment out index path the list path starts working, uncomment it start going to index.

Here are the rules v1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/? m/list.php?list_id=$1&date=$2 [QSA,L]
 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/? m/index.php?list_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here are the rules v2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/? m/index.php?list_id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^m/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/? m/list.php?list_id=$1&date=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Here are the two test urls:

http://www.example.com/m/blas3as should go to `index.php` (this works with rules on top)

http://www.example.com/m/blas3as/2021-01-01 -> `list.php` ( this link does not work it goes to `index.php`)

If I comment out:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^m/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/? m/index.php?list_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

http://www.example.com/m/blas3as/2021-01-01 -> `list.php` (this link starts working)

Obliviously the other link stops.

Comment: The problem is that the new, internal URL you are creating, `m/list.php?list_id=blas3as%26date=2021-01-01`, matches your second pattern as well. That’s because you did not anchor it at the end, so that a single letter or digit after the `m/` part satisfies the condition already, and can be followed by _anything else_ (so `m/list.php` is a match here, despite the fact it does contain a dot, which is not part of your character class.)

Comment: I have actually tried  moving rules making the list one first, and the index one second. it still did not help

Comment: You need to anchor your pattern at the end, with a `$`. (And should probably do the same for the other one as well, otherwise it could theoretically match more than you intended to as well.)